# php mysql displaying results as drop down list

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying veru hard, to get results from a database to be displayed as a drop down list.

Basically I am fetching the foreign key, its unique code and its name/title. I need to display it as a drop down list, to be entered correctly into a new table

```
        $sql = "SELECT quali_code, title FROM `qualifications`  ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);
    $result_array = array();
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $result_array[$r['quali_code']][] = $r;
    }
    return $result_array;
```

With that I would need to create a drop down list in HTMl/PHP to select the title from, but obviously storing the value. sort of `<list name=array[title] value=array[code] >`

At the moment I am already stuck at returning my SQl result in an array that works for me, and have no clue how I will then populate a dropdown list with the correct array results.

Sample code above on how i fetch the sql results and here how my array looks like:

```
Array ( [AAT] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => AAT [quali_code] => AAT [1] => AAT qualification [title] => AAT qualification ) ) [A_lev] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => A_lev [quali_code] => A_lev [1] => A levels [title] => A levels ) ) [HNC] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => HNC [quali_code] => HNC [1] => Fdsc/HNC [title] => Fdsc/HNC ) ) [Lan_ISLT] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Lan_ISLT [quali_code] => Lan_ISLT [1] => EISLT Qualification [title] => EISLT Qualification ) ) [Lan_qua] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Lan_qua [quali_code] => Lan_qua [1] => Language qualification [title] => Language qualification ) ) [Nat_Dip] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Nat_Dip [quali_code] => Nat_Dip [1] => National Diploma [title] => National Diploma ) ) )
```

Bare in mind I am totally new to PHP. Any help would be appreciated. But this array looks useless to me, and am not sure how to populate a list. The file where I fetch the result / array, is not the location where I populate the array into a list.

Many thanks for any hints on this matter

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysql). If you care to learn, [here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) is a quite good PDO-related tutorial.

Comment: thx for that, I will def look into this once i get this project done. Am under big time pressure. What would this one statement then look like, for example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all you're trying to do is echo these rows into a dropdown:

```
$sql = "SELECT quali_code, title FROM `qualifications` ORDER BY title ";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$quali_code = $r['quali_code'];
$result_array[$quali_code][] = $r['title'];
}


echo "<select name='x'>";
foreach($result_array as $q_code => $value)
{
    foreach($value as $title) {
    echo "<option value='" . $q_code . "'>" . $title . "</option>";
    }
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: any idea how I could return a dimensional array before printing them into a list ? My functions to do with DB connections, are in different files tyhan the file where I will use it !

Comment: so i first need to create an array I can work with, pass it to a different file, then print them there as a list

Comment: apart from the fact that when looking at it, I struggel understanding the loops to print it. Becasue the q_code, value and title variable in the loops is made up, but still it prints the items correctly. I guess the first loop, indicates the first part of teh array, second loop is for second part of array !?

Comment: yeah those var names are just designated to refer to the item the pointer is currently on. foreach($array as $key => $value)

Answer (score 1):

It's been awhile since I've used PHP, however, I remember this is how I printed out columns from a MySQL query. Use $r["columnName"] in the while loop. There may be semantic erros but this should give you a pretty good idea.

```
 echo "<select>";
 while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
    echo "<option value=\".$r['quali_code'].\">.$r['title'].</option>";
 }
 echo "</select>";
```

I used http://www.tizag.com/phpT/ to teach myself PHP. They have many great tutorials. Here's the link for a MySQL/PHP tutorial on Tizag: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/.

Happy coding.

Comment: thx for the answer and the links !! really appreciated, I will def look through the site on occasions !