# populating dropdown list from mysql data (remove from dropdown if in separate DB)- php/html

Tags: php, html, mysql

### Update 02:

As requested in the comments on my original question I am including my actual schema and will try and explain better based on what FunkFortyNiner said.

Any confusion or if you are unsure please comment and ask me questions! I am unable to go into PHP chat due to my rep and have gone over this question numerous times now!

### DB_2

```
Field    Type    Null    Key    Default    Extra
id      int(11)    NO    PRI    NULL    auto_increment
key    varchar(25) NO           NULL
r_name varchar(50) NO           NULL
r_uid  int(255)    NO           NULL
```

### DB_1

```
Field     Type       Null    Key    Default    Extra
id        int(11)     NO     PRI    NULL    auto_increment
u_name    varchar(50) NO            NULL
pass      varchar(255)NO            NULL
sub_start datetime    NO            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
sub_end   datetime    NO            NULL
is_r      int(1)      NO            NULL
admin     int(1)      NO            NULL
a_key     varchar(25) NO            NULL
```

Okay so far everything that I have done is working fine and as I want it too.

I have asked this question for help with doing the part I am stuck on.

Say **DB_2** is filled with some data.

I have a form on my site currently which when I fill it out it inserts the data into **DB_1.**

I want to add a dropdown to the form to display the keys from **DB_2** (this part is easy and plenty of already existing questions on this)

What I am actually stuck on is then having it so once the key has been taken from **DB_2** and inserted into **DB_1** by my form I no longer want to be able to select that key from the dropdown (otherwise I run this risk of adding duplicates!

I hope this is easier to understand and less confusing/likely to be seen as a duplicate! Please feel free to ask my any questions or to further explain something before you just write this question off as unnecessary or already asked!

Thanks a lot for taking the time to read all of this! :)

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

---

### Original Question (prior to being re-explained)

I have a quick question on a topic that I'm quite a noob about. I have a website I made that connects to a mysql database through php.

I have a form which I want to include a dropdown in and I want the data inside the dropdown to be taken from a column in my DB.

The thing is I also want it so that once that data is then saved in my DB it no longer shows up in the dropdown.

So example db schema

```
DB_1
------------------
Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3
------------------

DB_2
--------------------
Column_1 | Column_2
--------------------
```

### Example/Explanation of what I want to do:

So my form inserts data into DB_1
I want the dropdown to display all the results from DB_2/Column_1

Once DB_2/Column_1 matches DB_1/Column_3 for example then I no longer want that value to show up in the dropdown anymore.

Hope that makes sense and I explained it well enough!

Thanks :)

EDIT:
Not a Duplicate Question! This was marked as duplicate and suggested the following:
[php mysql displaying results as drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252307/php-mysql-displaying-results-as-drop-down-list)
Answer: "Assuming all you're trying to do is echo these rows into a dropdown:"

That is **not** all that I am trying to do. I also do not want the data to show up in the dropdown if it appears in DB_1

Hope this clarifies things! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the option from **DB_2** not to appear on the dropdown after its selected and saved, you can simply run another query that deletes the row from **DB_2** immediately after its submitted to **DB_1**.

Or better still, have a **Status** column on **DB_2** with a **0** or **1** value, default value being **1** and run an **UPDATE** query to change it to **0** after its been selected and saved. On your form dropdown you only query rows with **Status** as 1.